# How to convert or write PHP recursive function into mysql recursive stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**Question:**

How to convert or write PHP recursive function into mysql recursive stored procedure?

**Problem:**

The below php recursive taking too much loading time to get the parent child nodes. So please tell me how to improve performance by writing stored procedure in mysql.

**MY PHP Code:**

```
  <?php
function display_children($parent, $level) 
{
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testing_purpose");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT a.parent,a.id, a.label, a.link, Deriv1.Count FROM `menu` a  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT parent, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM `menu` GROUP BY parent) Deriv1 ON a.id = Deriv1.parent WHERE a.parent=" . $parent);
    echo "<ul class='menu'>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        if ($row['Count'] > 0)
        {
            echo "<li style='display:none;' id='" . $row['parent'] . "' onclick=id_func('" . $row['id'] . "')>" . $row['label'];
            display_children($row['id'], $level + 1);
            echo "</li>";
        } 
        elseif ($row['Count']==0) 
        {
            echo "<li style='display:none;' id='" . $row['parent'] . "' onclick=id_func('" . $row['id'] . "')>" . $row['label'] . "</li>";
        } else;
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    mysqli_close($con);
}
display_children(0,1);
?>
```

**Note:**

I am beginner in mysql stored procedure

Comment: Parent ? SQL ? Menu display ? Performance problems ? These are keywords that make me immediately think about [the nested set model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model), a way to represent a tree like your menu without a parent_id column like you probably have. Modelizing your tree with this technique will lead to queries that are way easier to write, and better performance. You can read [this article](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) if you want a good explanation. Not sure a stored procedure will help you at all.

Comment: I agree, I work with nested set implementations and the operations you can do with one query (reading the tree, inserting nodes) is impressive. I'd add that this question - if a stored procedure is still required - would be better with an attempt. As it is, it's a bit of a "please convert my code for me", whereas readers will generally be looking for prior effort.